# Component is not defined in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

using login function as component throws an error like this:
'LoginModal' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
I dont know why this happening.
Thanks in advance.

```
export default class Login extends Component {

    state={
        loading: false,
        modalShow: false,
        clicked: false,
        password:''
    }

    LoginModal = () => {
        return <Modal {...this.props} size="lg" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
              <Modal.Header closeButton>An otp has been sent to your Email!</Modal.Header>
                <p>something...</p>
                  <Button variant="outline-primary" onClick={this.setState({modalShow:false})} >Change Password</Button>  
            </Modal>
    }
    handleForgetPassword = () => {
        this.setState({modalShow: true})
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
       .....
    }

    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="login-wrapper">
                        <p onClick={this.handleForgetPassword} className="forgot-password">forgot password?</p>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <LoginModal
                    show={this.state.modalShow}
                    onHide={() => this.setState({modalShow:false})}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: add `const LoginModal` or `let LoginModal`

Comment: tried it throws error too. using in under render function works but everytime onchange event coccurs. modal get rerenders every time

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the state in the constructor
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        loading: false,
        modalShow: false,
        clicked: false,
        password:''
    }
```

Also, fix the render method as it's having a missing , or an extra closing tag

```
render() { 
    return (
        <div>
            <div id="login-wrapper">
                    <p onClick={this.handleForgetPassword} className="forgot-password">forgot password?</p>
             </div>  
            <LoginModal
                show={this.state.modalShow}
                onHide={() => this.setState({modalShow:false})}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not referencing `LoginModal` correctly. You should do something like this instead:

Create a standalone component and then pass props to it

```js
const LoginModal = ({onClick, ...props}) => {
        return <Modal {...props} size="lg" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
              <Modal.Header closeButton>An otp has been sent to your Email!</Modal.Header>
                <p>something...</p>
                  <Button variant="outline-primary" onClick={onClick} >Change Password</Button>  
            </Modal>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
return (
        <div>
             ......
            {this.LoginModal()}
       </div>
)
```